# How to select a file from the server or remote machine?

Tags: ms-access, vb6

Am new to VB 6.0

How to select a file from the other system?

I want to access a file from the other system  or server?

Need VB 6 code Help

Comment: In what context? A file open dialog? A SQL statement?

Comment: You are going to have to clarify the question. I understand that English may not be your first language, but in its current form the question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Code: Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider =Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "DataSource = C:DBase.mdb"
cn.Open
```

You will need to change the Datasource to the name and address of your file.